Multiple rows in a single row in power bi
Could some one help me how to achieve the below scenario in power bi for table visual.



User
Report 1
Report 2
Report 3




David
x




David

y



David


Z



Note: report 1, report 2, report 3 are calculated columns in power bi
I want the Output like below.



User
Report 1
Report 2
Report 3




David
x
y
z




If your data always contains values in one column/row per user, you can select User column in the table visual and select first value from your calculated columns.
Here is my sample table with 3 calculated columns for David-

And, here is the output (you can rename the column name)-


Behavior when a report name selected in the slicer


Calculated columns-
report 1 = if(your_table[report] = "report 1", "report 1")
report 2 = if(your_table[report] = "report 2", "report 2")
report 3 = if(your_table[report] = "report 3", "report 3")


Thanks for your solution it worked for me, but if i have a slicer on report list "report1","report2","report3" and when i am selecting report1 it is displaying all three reports data, is there any way only to show report 1 data when i select report1 and rest of the columns should be in blank.

I can see the other columns showing nothing when a report is selected in the slicer (image added). do you want to hide the entire column instead?

No Need to hide if it is blank is also fine, But for me when i apply filter on report name it is not working.  can you help me how you have calculated the "first report1", first report2, first report3 columns.

Do this in Power Query. Select User column and unpivot other columns.

Then select the attribute column and pivot with following options.



OR
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
a=Table.ToColumns(Source),
b= List.Transform(List.RemoveFirstN(a,1), each List.RemoveNulls(_)),
in Table.FromColumns({List.Repeat({a{0}{0}},List.Count(b{0}))}&b, Table.ColumnNames(Source))

or
let Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
z= Table.FromColumns(List.Transform(Table.ToColumns(Source), each List.RemoveNulls(_)),Table.ColumnNames(Source)),
#"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(z, each ([Report 1] <>null))
in #"Filtered Rows"

